# EntityFramework - Store Procedure (Null to Int32)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a store procedure for fill my instance.

```
{
    SqlParameter[] sqParams = new SqlParameter[]
    {
        new SqlParameter{ParameterName = "@rn", Value = firm.Rn, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input},
        new SqlParameter{ParameterName = "@startDate", Value = startDate, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input},
        new SqlParameter{ParameterName = "@endDate", Value = endDate, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input},
        new SqlParameter{ParameterName = "@spmo", Value = firm.Bkm == 3 ? 0 : 1, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input},
        new SqlParameter{ParameterName = "@pmo", Value = 0, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input}
    };

    return _context.Database.SqlQuery<SupportTypeBased>("s_FirmSupportAnalysis @rn, @startDate, @endDate, @spmo, @pmo", sqParams).ToList();
}
```

And my returning entity.

```
public class SupportTypeBased : IDTOEntity
    {
        public string RECTYPE { get; set; }
        public int MCOUNT { get; set; }
        public int DCOUNT { get; set; }
    }
```

Query database result.
[image]

As you can see, the problem is database returning 'NULL' for "DCOUNT" property in my class which is **Int32** type. So how can I say like if value is null, make it 0 without *do not* touch my store procedure or *do not* change property type to **Int?**

Comment: You need to touch one side choose which wisely :)

Comment: As long as Entity Framework is doing the mapping for you then you cannot change `NULL` to `0` - you will **have to** change the sproc or your entity type property.